# Where I set index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count in ES 2.3?

Tags: elasticsearch

Where I set index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count in ES 2.3?
Didn't find it in elasticsearch.yml
Or should I just add it to the config file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any Elasticsearch setting that starts with `index.` is intended as an index-level setting, which means for each index (e.g., in a template). Any setting that starts with `indices.` is intended to be a cluster-level setting, which means the `elasticsearch.yml`.

Prior to Elasticsearch 5.0 (**not** released as of this writing), you can set `index.`-type settings in the `elasticsearch.yml`, but this is trappy behavior because you might forget to set it in one file.

So, set it in the index settings:

```
PUT /my-index/_settings
{
  "index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count" : 1
}
```

You could set it for all *existing* indices:

```
PUT /_settings
{
  "index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count" : 1
}
```

A common question is: why isn't this a global setting? It kind of is because you set a global template to control these kind of properties:

```
PUT /_template/my_default_settings
{
  "template" : "*",
  "settings" : {
    "number_of_shards" : 2,
    "index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count" : 1
  }
}
```

But more importantly, by being an index-level setting, it enables you to change it dynamically as the hardware changes on the nodes that the index lives on. For example, when the index is created, then it most likely needs to be written to the most, but over time it might not be written too as frequently and so it can be moved to bigger, but slower nodes where the merge scheduler needs to be controlled. In such an example, you would only want to set the thread count after it moves, thus allowing the theoretically faster (but smaller) machine to merge as fast as it can.

Comment: Thank you. Also found it here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html

If you are using spinning media instead of SSD, you need to add this to your elasticsearch.yml:

index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count: 1